# Free SSH App for RIM's BlackBerry (Bold - 9700)?

Tags: blackberry

I have found a few SSH programs for the BlackBerry through BB App World but they are rather costly. Does anyone know if there may be a free one available somewhere or is the App World all inclusive?

Thanks.

Farhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BBSSH looks like it should work. I used to use MidpSSH, but it's hasn't had a release in a while. BBSSH continues MidpSSH by making it a Blackberry specific app.

http://bbssh.org/wiki/en/Home

http://marcparadise.com/articles/tag/bbssh

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at MidpSSH, but followed the BBSSH links from their site (prior to seeing your post) and gave it a try.  BBSH is better than I remember MidpSSH being.  It even kind of works on my storm :)

Comment: Just started using bbssh after seeing this question/answer being posted here.
Apart from not accepting my putty generated private key (keeps throwing up errors), it's an amazing little application!

Now I can WOL and do other cool stuff from my phone :)

Answer (score 1):

How about web based client. If you have full browser on you phone you may be able to use it. And of course there is the issue of security, but nonetheless its an option.

Here is one http://www.serfish.com/console/

Comment: While not for the BB, as you mentioned, that URL is handy nonetheless. Appreciate the link!